# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "23 "

Tags: java, string, numberformatexception, parseint

I gave 23 (looks like a proper string) as input, but stil get NumberFormatException. Please point out where I went wrong.

PS I was trying to solve "chef and strings problem" on codechef

Relevent code:

```
Scanner cin=new Scanner(System.in);
      cin.useDelimiter("\n");
      String data=cin.next();
      System.out.println(data);

      /*
       * @param Q no. of chef's requests
       */
      String tempStr=cin.next();
      System.out.println(tempStr);;
      int Q = Integer.parseInt(tempStr);
```

Output:

```
sdfgsdg
sdfgsdg

23
23

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "23
"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at Chef.RegexTestHarness.main(RegexTestHarness.java:24)
```

Complete program:

```
package Chef;
//
//TODO codechef constraints
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

//TODO RETURN TYPE
class RegexTestHarness
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  { 

      Scanner cin=new Scanner(System.in);
      cin.useDelimiter("\n");
      String data=cin.next();
      System.out.println(data);

      /*
       * @param Q no. of chef's requests
       */
      String tempStr=cin.next();
      System.out.println(tempStr);;
      int Q = Integer.parseInt(tempStr);

      for(int i=0; i<Q; i++)
      {
          /*
           * @param s chef's request
           */
           String s= cin.next();//request

//void getParam() (returning multiple parameters problem)
   //{a b L R
   //where a:start letter
   //b: end lettert
    //L: minStartIndex
    //L<=S[i]<=E[i]<=R
           //R is the maxEndIndex

//TODO transfer to main

    char a=s.charAt(0);
    char b=s.charAt(3);
    int L=0, R=0;
    /*
     * @param indexOfR in the request string s, we separate R (which is maxEndIndex of chef's
     * good string inside data string)
     * . To do that, we first need the index of R itself in request string s 
     */
    int indexOfR= s.indexOf(" ", 5) +1;
    System.out.println("indexOfR is:" + s.indexOf(" ", 5));

    L= Integer.parseInt( s.substring(5, indexOfR - 2) );
    //TODO check if R,L<10^6

    R=Integer.parseInt( s.substring(indexOfR) );

    //}  ( end getparam() )
  //-----------------------------------
    //now we have a b L R

    //String good="";
    //TODO add other constraints (like L<si.....) here
    if(a !=b)
    {   int startInd=data.indexOf(a, L), endInd=data.lastIndexOf(b, R);
    int output=0, temp;

    while((startInd<endInd)&&(startInd != (-1) ) && ( endInd != (-1) ))
        {

          temp = endInd;
            while((startInd<endInd))
            {


            //good= good+ s.substring(startInd, endInd);
            output++;


            endInd=data.lastIndexOf(b, endInd);
            }
            startInd=data.indexOf(a, startInd);
            //TODO if i comment the line below, eclipse says tat the variable temp 
            //(declared at line 68) is not used. Whereas it is used at 68 
            //(and 83, the line below) 
            endInd=temp;

        }
    System.out.println(output);

    }





      }//end for


  cin.close();
  }


}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your String has a trailing white space.

```
int Q = Integer.parseInt(tempStr.trim());
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Scanner.nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) and avoid to parse the String.

Also it's useful the method [Scanner.hasNextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the closing doublequote `"` on the exception - it is positioned on the next line, meaning that the input string has `'\n'` or `'\r'` at the end.

You can fix this by calling `trim()` before passing the string to the parsing method, but you would be better off having `next()` strip the end-of-line character for you by using system-specific line separator, like this:

```
cin.useDelimiter(System.lineSeparator());
```

or by calling `hasNextInt`/`nextInt` to let the scanner do the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

It's my standard answer to such questions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "23
"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at Chef.RegexTestHarness.main(RegexTestHarness.java:24)
```

means:

```
There was an error. We try to give you as much information as possible
It was an Exception in main thread. It's called NumberFormatException and has occurred for input "23\n".
which was invoked from method main in file RegexTestHarness.java in line 24.
```

In other words, you tried to parse `"23\n"` to an `int` what Java can't do with method `Integer.parseInt`. Java has provided beautiful stacktrace which tells you exactly what the problem is. The tool you're looking for is **debugger** and using **breakpoints** will allow you to inspect the *state* of you application at the chosen moment.

As mentioned before, it's safe to use `tempStr.trimm()` before parsing to the int.

Answer (score 1):

Input String if parsed as integer then its must be valid integer value no decimal, space, line-break or any other character. So make sure The Input String throw in exception is valid integer or not if contain any other character, decimal, space/line-break then try to remove that.